# CG runtime linker error with cmake project (g++)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cmake, cg

I'm getting these linker errors:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgGL

I'm using the FindCg.cmake frome here: http://code.google.com/p/nvidia-texture-tools/source/browse/branches/2.0/cmake/FindCg.cmake?r=452

Then adding the found libraries with target_link_libraries..

When I run make with VERBOSE=1 (See below) it looks like it passes the right path of the libraries (/usr/lib64/libCgGL.so and /usr/lib64/libCg.so)

```
01- 0:30:09 loony@T-linux> make FightSpace VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/loony/git/tengine -B/home/loony/git/tengine/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 FightSpace
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/loony/git/tengine -B/home/loony/git/tengine/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles 91
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build.make Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPlatform /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build.make Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  57
[  1%] Built target TEPlatform
make -f Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build.make Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TECore /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build.make Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
[ 40%] Built target TECore
make -f Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build.make Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEngine /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEngine /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build.make Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93
[ 53%] Built target TEngine
make -f Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEInputSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEInputSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  47 48 49 50 51
[ 59%] Built target TEInputSystem
make -f Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build.make Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPhysics /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build.make Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  52 53 54 55
[ 63%] Built target TEPhysics
make -f Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build.make Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TERendering /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TERendering /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build.make Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78
[ 86%] Built target TERendering
make -f Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEGraphicsSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEGraphicsSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  41 42 43 44 45 46
[ 93%] Built target TEGraphicsSystem
make -f Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build.make Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TETransformSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TETransformSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build.make Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  79 80 81
[ 96%] Built target TETransformSystem
make -f Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/build.make Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/FightSpace /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/FightSpace /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/build.make Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
Linking CXX executable ../../../Executables/FightSpace
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/FightSpace && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/FightSpaceGame.cpp.o CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/TEAssetImporter.cpp.o  -o ../../../Executables/FightSpace  -L/opt/boost/lib  -L/usr/lib64/libCg.so  -L/usr/lib64/libCgGL.so  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/FightSpace  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Events  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Intersection  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Math  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Network  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Resources  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/IO  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Images  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Utils  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Collision  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Physics  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEngine/Engine  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Win  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Linux  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEGraphicsSystem  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TETransformSystem  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEInputSystem -rdynamic ../TECore/libTECore.a ../TEngine/libTEngine.a ../TEGraphicsSystem/libTEGraphicsSystem.a ../TEPhysics/libTEPhysics.a ../TETransformSystem/libTETransformSystem.a ../TEPlatform/libTEPlatform.a ../TEInputSystem/libTEInputSystem.a -lCg -lCgGL ../TERendering/libTERendering.a ../../../Externals/glew-1.7.0/lib/glew32.lib -lCg -lCgGL -lGLU -lGL -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext ../TEngine/libTEngine.a ../TECore/libTECore.a ../TEPlatform/libTEPlatform.a ../../../Externals/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/buildscons/linux-gcc-4.7.2/src/lib_json/libjson_linux-gcc-4.7.2_libmt.a -Wl,-rpath,/opt/boost/lib:/usr/lib64/libCg.so:/usr/lib64/libCgGL.so:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/FightSpace:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Events:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Intersection:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Math:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Network:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Resources:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/IO:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Images:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Utils:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Collision:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Physics:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEngine/Engine:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Win:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Linux:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEGraphicsSystem:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TETransformSystem:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEInputSystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../Executables/FightSpace] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[2]: *** [Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[1]: *** [Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make: *** [FightSpace] Error 2
~/git/tengine/build @ (git::master)
01- 0:30:21 loony@T-linux>
```

## ==========================================

EDIT:

After removing link_directories lines in cmake file as sugested by Fraser in reply below I get this output instead

```
01- 1:58:59 loony@T-linux> make FightSpace VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/loony/git/tengine -B/home/loony/git/tengine/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 FightSpace
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/loony/git/tengine -B/home/loony/git/tengine/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles 91
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build.make Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPlatform /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build.make Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEPlatform/CMakeFiles/TEPlatform.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  57
[  1%] Built target TEPlatform
make -f Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build.make Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TECore /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build.make Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TECore/CMakeFiles/TECore.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
[ 40%] Built target TECore
make -f Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build.make Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEngine /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEngine /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build.make Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEngine/CMakeFiles/TEngine.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93
[ 53%] Built target TEngine
make -f Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build.make Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TETransformSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TETransformSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build.make Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TETransformSystem/CMakeFiles/TETransformSystem.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  79 80 81
[ 57%] Built target TETransformSystem
make -f Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build.make Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPhysics /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build.make Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEPhysics/CMakeFiles/TEPhysics.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  52 53 54 55
[ 61%] Built target TEPhysics
make -f Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build.make Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TERendering /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TERendering /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build.make Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TERendering/CMakeFiles/TERendering.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78
[ 84%] Built target TERendering
make -f Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEGraphicsSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEGraphicsSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEGraphicsSystem/CMakeFiles/TEGraphicsSystem.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  41 42 43 44 45 46
[ 91%] Built target TEGraphicsSystem
make -f Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEInputSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEInputSystem /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build.make Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `Code/TEInputSystem/CMakeFiles/TEInputSystem.dir/build'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/loony/git/tengine/build/CMakeFiles  47 48 49 50 51
[ 96%] Built target TEInputSystem
make -f Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/build.make Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/depend
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/loony/git/tengine /home/loony/git/tengine/Code/FightSpace /home/loony/git/tengine/build /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/FightSpace /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make -f Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/build.make Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
Linking CXX executable ../../../Executables/FightSpace
cd /home/loony/git/tengine/build/Code/FightSpace && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/FightSpaceGame.cpp.o CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/TEAssetImporter.cpp.o  -o ../../../Executables/FightSpace  -L/opt/boost/lib  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/FightSpace  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Events  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Intersection  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Math  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Network  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Resources  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/IO  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Images  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Utils  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Collision  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Physics  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEngine/Engine  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Win  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Linux  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEGraphicsSystem  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TETransformSystem  -L/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEInputSystem -rdynamic ../TECore/libTECore.a ../TEngine/libTEngine.a ../TEGraphicsSystem/libTEGraphicsSystem.a ../TEPhysics/libTEPhysics.a ../TETransformSystem/libTETransformSystem.a ../TEPlatform/libTEPlatform.a ../TEInputSystem/libTEInputSystem.a -lCg -lCgGL ../TERendering/libTERendering.a ../../../Externals/glew-1.7.0/lib/glew32.lib -lCg -lCgGL -lGLU -lGL -lSM -lICE -lX11 -lXext ../TEngine/libTEngine.a ../TECore/libTECore.a ../TEPlatform/libTEPlatform.a ../../../Externals/jsoncpp-src-0.5.0/buildscons/linux-gcc-4.7.2/src/lib_json/libjson_linux-gcc-4.7.2_libmt.a -Wl,-rpath,/opt/boost/lib:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/FightSpace:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Events:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Intersection:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Math:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Network:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Resources:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/IO:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Images:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TECore/Utils:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Collision:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPhysics/Physics:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEngine/Engine:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Win:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEPlatform/Linux:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEGraphicsSystem:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TETransformSystem:/home/loony/git/tengine/Code/TEInputSystem
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCg
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lCgGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../Executables/FightSpace] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[2]: *** [Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make[1]: *** [Code/FightSpace/CMakeFiles/FightSpace.dir/rule] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/loony/git/tengine/build'
make: *** [FightSpace] Error 2
~/git/tengine/build @ (git::master)
01- 1:59:08 loony@T-linux>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following part looks suspicious:

> ```
> -L/usr/lib64/libCg.so  -L/usr/lib64/libCgGL.so
> ```

`-L` should be followed by a path to a directory which will be searched by the linker when looking for subsequent libs specified via `-l`.

I would expect this to be `-L/usr/lib64` in this case.

Are you sure you're including `${CG_LIBRARY}` and `${CG_GL_LIBRARY}` in a [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) call and not a [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories) call by mistake?

---

**Edit**

Based on the comments below, you can do the following to get things working:

```
get_filename_component(CgLibPath ${CG_LIBRARY} PATH)
get_filename_component(CgGlLibPath ${CG_GL_LIBRARY} PATH)
link_directories(${CgLibPath} ${CgGlLibPath})
```

This should work, but note that the use of `link_directories` is not recommended, even in its own documentation.

Comment: I was actually including it both with target_link_libraries and link_directories.. but after removing the link_directories line I still get the same errors.. I updated my question with the new output

Comment: Now it doesn't have the -L at all though?

Comment: Also;  message(${Cg_LIBRARIES}) and message(${Cg_GL_LIBRARIES}) prints out the full path of the files..

Comment: Strange.  Can you show your exact `target_link_libraries` call please?

Comment: elseif(UNIX)
 target_link_libraries(
  TERendering
  TECore
  TEPlatform
  ${glew_libraries}
  ${Cg_LIBRARIES}
  ${Cg_GL_LIBRARIES}
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
endif()

Comment: but in the build output it does't show that its passing the full path to the libs? how would it know where it is? to install cg I just downloaded a tar file and unpacket it to / and it had the /usr/lib64 structure inside.. do I need to inform the linker system of where to find it?

Comment: Well, `target_link_libraries` should take care of that if you're passing the absolute paths.  Are you sure you're giving the full paths?  The variables mentioned in FindCg.cmake are `${CG_LIBRARY}` and `${CG_GL_LIBRARY}`, rather than `${Cg_LIBRARIES}` and `${Cg_GL_LIBRARIES}`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to derive the missing `-L` part of the command.

Comment: I realized I had an old version of the FindCg.cmake script which used Cg_ for the variables.. I downloaded the new script and now it seems to be working.. getting some other errors now.. but not related and I should be able to find a solution to them.. Thanks for you help. Accepting your answer :)

Comment: This actually didn't work.. I commented out the code that included the cg stuff so thats why it compiled :p even adding the path with link_directories doesn't make it show up when I run make with VERBOSE=1 :(